# plot bar chart number of ticks on xaxis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a timeseries dataframe like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=100),
              columns=["Random"],
              index=pd.date_range("20180101", freq='M',periods=100))
```

I am trying to do a simple bar plot out of it but wanted to have a control on the number of tick labels on the xaxis otherwise the labels are squashed. 
My actual data size is much larger than this sample. After searching other similar issues, I have tried below:

```
ax=df.plot.bar()
plt.title('Random Plot')
n=10
ticks = ax.axis.get_ticklocs()
ticklabels = [i.get_text() for i in ax.get_ticklabels()]
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks[::n])
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels[::n])
plt.show()
```

But I got an error---
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get_ticklocs'

I wanted to change the value of `n` so that i can change which month label to be displayed on the plot. Not sure if that is a sensible way to do and why it causes erros. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missed an `x` in `ticks = ax.axis.get_ticklocs()`. You only need `ax.get_xticklabels()` to get a list of tick labels, no need for the list comprehension.

Note that you will probably have to pass a formatter to your x axis in order to get the dates in a format that you want.

Also, you are mixing `ax.xaxis.get` and `ax.get` which might be confusing. I've made that consistent, so your code will then become:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,30,size=100),
              columns=["Random"],
              index=pd.date_range("20180101", freq='M',periods=100))

ax=df.plot.bar()
plt.title('Random Plot')
n=10

ticks = ax.xaxis.get_ticklocs()
ticklabels = ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels()

ax.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks[::n])
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels(ticklabels[::n])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks very much David. Now seems that to control the number of ticks worked from the revised scripts. But it doesn't show correct axis labels. Instead of the dates (e.g., 2018-01-31), it gives 0, 10,20,30... why is it happen